# Function takes pointer to structure

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I have this structure in C

```
struct system_info
{  
   const char *name;     
   const char *version;  
   const char *extensions; 
   bool        path;    
};
```

And this function signature

```
void info(struct system_info *info);
```

I'm trying to use this function like this:

```
[DllImport("...")]
unsafe public static extern void info(info *test);



[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public unsafe struct info
{
    public char *name;
    public char *version;
    public char *extensions;

    public bool path;
}
```

And on my main:

```
info x = new info();
info(&x);
```

I'm getting an error, pointers cannot reference to marshaled structures, how can I manage this?

Comment: You are not close, have you researched this at all?  Declare the char* as string instead.  The bool needs an [UnmanagedType.U1].  The function should be void info(ref info arg), possibly requiring [In,Out].

Comment: actually I managed to get it working by using ref, as you just mentioned, the bool is working, I'll try string for the char*

Comment: Well after changing the char* to string it just exits without an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need at all to use `unsafe` here. I would do it like this:

```
public struct info
{
    public IntPtr name;
    public IntPtr version;
    public IntPtr extensions;
    public bool path;
}
```

And then the function is:

```
[DllImport("...")]
public static extern void getinfo(out info value);
```

You may need to specify the `Cdecl` calling convention, depending on the native code.

Call the function like this:

```
info value;
getinfo(out value);
string name = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(value.name);
// similarly for the other two strings fields
```

Since there is no mention of string length in the native code you posted, I'm assuming that the strings are allocated by the native code and that you don't need to to anything to deallocate them.

Comment: I got it working and I haven't had time to test the IntPtr (but since it works with char* I assume it does too)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using ref instead of *test like Hans Passant mentioned

```
[DllImport("...")]
unsafe public static extern void info(ref system_info test);
```